# HTML form with multiple select to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, ajax

I am quite a novice with javascript and I could do with some asssitance here.

I have a form which contains a multiple select field as below:

```
        <select name="services[]" class="required" multiple="multiple" >
        <option style="padding:5px;" value="">Pleae Select </option>
        <option style="padding:5px;" value="TAX CREDITS">TAX CREDITS </option>
         <option style="padding:5px;" value="CHILD BENEFIT">CHILD BENEFIT</option>
        <option style="padding:5px;" value="SELF EMPLOYMENT & CIS ISSUES">SELF EMPLOYMENT & CIS 
            ISSUES </option>
         <option style="padding:5px;" value="THE EMPLOYED (PAYE)">THE EMPLOYED (PAYE)</option>
        <option style="padding:5px;" value="OTHER SERVICES">OTHER SERVICES</option>
        </select>
```

The form when submitted is validated using javascript before being submnitted to the php engine using ajax. Below is the javascript which works fine for all the fields except the services field. I know services returns an array of values but the .val() doesn't seem to work for the arrayed field and returns blank. How should I set the line **"services":$('select[name="services"]').val(),** to return a value please?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function (e){
    $("#frmContact").on('submit',(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#mail-status").hide();
        $('#send-message').hide();
        $('#loader-icon').show();
        $.ajax({
            url: "contact.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType:'json',
            data: {
            "name":$('input[name="name"]').val(),
            "email":$('input[name="email"]').val(),
            "phone":$('input[name="phone"]').val(),
            "services":$('select[name="services"]').val(),
            "content":$('textarea[name="content"]').val(),
            },              
            success: function(response){
            $("#mail-status").show();
            $('#loader-icon').hide();
            if(response.type == "error") {
                $('#send-message').show();
                $("#mail-status").attr("class","error");                
            } else if(response.type == "message"){
                $('#send-message').hide();
                $("#mail-status").attr("class","success");                          
            }
            $("#mail-status").html(response.text);  
            },
            error: function(){} 
        });
    }));
});
</script>
```

Comment: How is this "php" related?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
$("select[name='services'] option:selected").val();
```

For multiple selectors

```
var multiple = [];
$.each($("select[name='services'] option:selected"), function(){            
        multiple.push($(this).val());
});
alert("Select values - " + multiple.join(", "));
```